# Shell script to modify variable with file name of multiple files in same directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have a multiple files in a directory, e.g.:

```
a01.txt
a02.txt
a03.txt 
etc...
```

Line 3 of all text files in the directory is as follows:

```
consumer[location].userid= constant
```

I want to replace the word "location" with the respective filename without extension in the third line of each file eg: as

```
consumer[a01].userid= constant    --------- for a01.txt
consumer[a02].userid= constant    --------- for a03.txt
etc
```

Can you please help?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, starting at the top: You want to replace a word (location) in a specific line of a file.
Google says, sed can do that:

```
sed -i "3s/location/foo/" file.ext
```

will replace the first occurence of "location" in the third line of the file "file.ext"

The string you want to replace location with, should be a filename without extension.
Since you know the extension, basename should work fine for that:

```
basename /path/to/file.ext .ext
```

will return "file".

Now loop through all the txt files in the directory:

```
for filename in directory/*.txt; do
# Do stuff
done
```

Combining these commands results in a short script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Assumes the script is located in the data directory
for filename in ./*.txt; do
    name=$(basename $filename .txt)
    echo "$filename -> $name"
    sed -i "3s/location/$name/" $filename
done
```

Comment: You probably mean `3s/location/foo/` (notice the `s`). Your current command is a syntax error.

Comment: Corrected. I also replaced -e with -i so it is changing the line in the file instead of echoing it.

Comment: You also want double quotes around `"$filename"` everywhere.

Comment: The script can be saved anywhere, you just need to *run* it in the directory where these files are.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt and kind response to my question. Your script did what exactly i need , good wishes to you.

Comment: The downvote was probably to discourage you from answering "gimme codez" questions. On Stack Overflow, "do my job for me" questions are strongly discouraged, because we do not want to ruin the job market for freelance programmers.

Comment: If that is really the reason, I don't think that rule should apply to simple shell questions. Even though, I agree that there should have been more effort on 7pkbeas part in the first place.